# like button like instagram crash after press

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I added new option to my app the user can like the places but when i press on the like `Button` i get crash [Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value]

**Code:**
`tableViewCell` button

```
@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.likeBtn.isEnabled = false
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    //let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
    let keyToPost = ref.child("Restaurant").childByAutoId().key


    ref.child("Restaurant").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                          //.child(self.id)
        if let post = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            let updateLikes: [String : Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
            ref.child("Restaurant").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in

                if error == nil {
                    ref.child("Restaurant").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        if let properties = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                            if let likes = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                let count = likes.count
                                self.likeLabel.text = "\(count) Likes this place"

                                let update = ["likes" : count]
                                ref.child("Restaurant").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)

                                self.likeBtn.isHidden = true
                                self.unlikeBtn.isHidden = false
                                self.likeBtn.isEnabled = true
                                print("Likes")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }


    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()
}
```

**Error Screenshot**
[image]

**Second Screenshot**
[image]

Could someone can help me,Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you update the error log?

Comment: done i added it in my qution image 2

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Copy and paste the errors into your question as text.

Comment: it's just (lldb) o more

Comment: To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: Please remove the pictures and include text. self.postID is probably nil which causes the crash. Also, you need to update your project and Podfile.

Comment: @Jay yes my problem in the postID so what i can do i already updated my project and Podfile

Comment: If you look back at your question, the included code does not show how the postID variable is defined so we won't be able to help without knowing that.

Comment: @Jay can i send my project for you

Comment: The issue you are describing needs to be minimal and duplicatable, so update your question with relevant information and we'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

```
let updateLikes: [String : Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
```

Probably there is no currentUser -> Force unwraps like to crash your application I'd avoid them as much as possible.
Where do you authenticate your current User?

How you sign in a User:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start

And then before your code I'd do something like that:

```
guard let userUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
return
}
```